# How to make it store all the things it prints in a file

Tags: python, file

Current program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

lookup = 'Loop time'

with open('log.lammps') as myFile:
    found = []
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line:
            print 'found at line:', num
            found.append(num)
print found
  a = int(found[0])
  b = int(found[1])
  c = int(found[2])
  d = int(found[3])

lookup = 'Memory usage per processor ='

with open('log.lammps') as myFile:
    found2 = []
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line:
           print 'found at line:', num
            found2.append(num)
print found2
e = int(found2[0])
f = int(found2[1])
g = int(found2[2])
h = int(found2[3])

x = 0
while x < len(found):
    a = found[x]
    e = found2[x]

    print "Some thing useful!"

    for w,line in enumerate(open("log.lammps")):
        if w >= e and w < a :
           print line,
           x += 1
```

How do i make it store the last while function into a document. I want to it make a file with the data that this program prints out so that I can have matlab read that file.

Comment: open a file at the start and write whatever you want to it in the code

Comment: you are able to open a file already why not just write to one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to redirect the output to a file. Let `script.py` be your python script:

```
./script.py > out.txt
```

Otherwise you can redirect the `stdout` to a file directly in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
sys.stdout = open('out.txt', 'w')

lookup = 'Loop time'
...
```

Now every `print` statement will be redirected to `out.txt`

Answer (score 0):

One very fast way is to replace `sys.stdout` with an open file descriptor.

```
f = open("file.txt","w")
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = f

while x < len(found):
    a = found[x]
    e = found2[x]

    print "Some thing useful!"

    for w,line in enumerate(open("log.lammps")):
        if w >= e and w < a :
           print line,
           x += 1

sys.stdout = old_stdout
f.close()
```

This will automatically redirect anything you print to `file.txt` instead of `stdout`. It's also a little hackish, though. It would be a better idea just to open the write file and then replace `print ...` with `f.write(...)` wherever you see it, since you don't have any functions that do complex printing.

(I'm assuming you only want the last `while` loop written to a file, as your question stated.)

Comment: You can also use `sys.__stdout__` instead of storing `old_stdout`

Comment: @hlt I was told not to do this, once.

Comment: True, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__) (I just checked): "However, the preferred way to do this is to explicitly save the previous stream before replacing it, and restore the saved object."

Answer (score 0):

Open a file at the start and write the data as you go:

```
with open('output.txt',"w") as out:
```

Wherever you print data just write it to a file also:

```
    print 'found at line:  {}'.format(num) 
    out.write('found at line:  {}\n'.format(num)) etc..
```

Just start your code like:

```
with open('output.txt',"w") as out:
    with open('log.lammps') as myFile:
       # continue with your code
```

Answer (score -1):

The important thing about `sys.stdout` is that you have to `import sys` instead of `from sys import stdout`

i.e. this **won't** redirect your output to a file:

```
>>> from sys import stdout
>>> stdout = open('/dev/null', 'w')
>>> print 1
1  # not working
```

Comment: This is a comment on TheSoundDefense's answer, not a separate answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't have 50 reputation to comment others answers.

Comment: See the [help on answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help). You shouldn't abuse answers as comments just because you don't have privileges to comment. All that will do is get you lowered rep, delaying getting to that 50 rep, or if you piss off a mod badly enough, banned.